# Powerpoint VBA: Clearing shape color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to write a code that search a shape color and then position it into somewhere.

Example:

```
If shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(210, 210, 210) Then 

With shape
        .Width = 700 
        .Height = 20
        .Top = 80
        .Left = 30
        .Name = "TitleTextBox"
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.Transparency = 1.0  '(somehow when I type 1.0 it will become 1#, not sure why on this also)
End With

End if
```

**How I use my code:**

I using this code to add a fill color Grey = RGB(210,210,210) to certain shapes then clear the color and reposition the shape to where I wanted

However, when I run this code again, the shape that has added the Grey color will get reposition again, even though it doesn't have any fill to it.

Somehow, I felt the shape has remembered the color apply to them, which isn't what I wanted.

Appreciate if any one can provide me some insight on how I can overcome this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Vityata's answer should do the job for you.  The reason you're having problems is that even though the shape's fill isn't visible, its fill *color* attribute is still the original grey color that you're searching for, so it gets found again.

Comment: Hi Thanks Steve for your reply. I'm trying to clear the original grey color. when I try to fill the color manually with "No Fill" it works, is there include the code as VBA ? because I doesn't want to replace the shape with another color as even with white, it might overlay other text on slide and cover them.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim sh      As Shape
    Dim sld     As Slide

    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(210, 210, 210) Then
            With sh
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .Width = 700
                .Height = 20
                .Top = 80
                .Left = 30
                .Name = "TitleTextBox"
                .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
                .Fill.Transparency = 1#
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Once you find the grey shape, make sure that you change its color to `RGB(0,0,0)`. Thus, it will not be grey any more and will not be taken into account, if you run the code again. I have done it with this line:

```
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Vityata, thanks for your assistance. my bad, I should have made it clearer, I understand your solution will since the fill color has changed, I have tried to add .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (255,255,255) to make the fill box white also but realized that sometimes the fill color will block out someother textbox in other slides. I was wonder if there is any way to set the fill color to transparent rather any forecolor.RGB? I tried .Fill.Visible = msoFalse but this way the text box will still get selected eventhough the fill color has been removed.

Comment: @GeraldTow - this link should help for the transparancy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/fillformat-transparency-property-powerpoint Or this -> `ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5`

Comment: Thanks Vityata, I tried this method, but the grey color fill that has been set before is still "remembered." eventhough transparency set to 0%. may I ask do you know of any code that let a shape have "No Fill" totally? Thanks for your help so far. Greatly appreciate